# NetBeans Code Completion on Doctrine 2 Entities?

Tags: php, netbeans, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to use NetBeans code completion on Doctrine 2 entities?  I have a simple entity created with some protected variables and public methods.  I create the entity manager in my bootstrap.php file like this:

`$em = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);`

I access my Doctrine entity like this:

`$myObject=$em->getRepository('Entities\MyObject')->findOneById(1);`

The actual code works fine.  The problem is that NetBeans is not providing code completion on the methods or properties of the MyObject.  How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code sample Netbeans code completion is not able to provide code completion, because your using the method getRepository() in conjunction with parameters. Netbeans would have to compile the function getRepository() to examine the return type.

A solution for this is to use type hinting for that variable:

```
public function x() {
    /* @var $myObject MyObjectType */
    $myObject = $em->getRepository('Entities\MyObject')->findOneById(1);
}
```

Now you're able to use $myObject with code completion.